# Youtube-dl Unable to extract video data

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

I have a web-app that uses youtube-dl to download videos, for some time I getting YouTube said: Unable to extract video data, I know it's not my web-app but the Youtube-dl that's causing it because it happens in the terminal also.

I found that it's due to the extractor [see here on github repo](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/d4f53af482cc47b0473a3576da7ad902bea4ac39/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L1831)

```
        if not video_info:
            unavailable_message = extract_unavailable_message()
            if not unavailable_message:
                unavailable_message = 'Unable to extract video data'
            raise ExtractorError(
                'YouTube said: %s' % unavailable_message, expected=True, video_id=video_id)
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).